# Customizing ArcGIS Online Popup to show Related Tables

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

How do I get related table attributes to appear all on the first page of a popup in an ArcGIS Online web map?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you need to make sure that your original relationship class has a 1-to-1 relationship. If it's 1-to-1, then you can simply add the relationship fields to your pop-up. If it's 1-to-many, you only get the option to add the "summary statistics" for a field from the related table.

You can read about it at [Configure pop-ups (Map Viewer Classic)](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_09B2E0D22072457AAC8D025377DD7CF9).